# Compute the distribution of the number of hours $T$ that we can use the flashlight.

Tags: probability

> We have a flashlight that uses two batteries and we have a package of
> four new batteries. Suppose that each battery has an independent
> exponential($\lambda$) lifetime. Compute the distribution of the
> number of hours $T$ that we can use the flashlight.

### Try

Call $X$ the lifetime of each battery which given is that $X$ is Exp($\lambda$). Let $T$ be number of hours we can use the flashlight.

LEt $Y$ be the lifetime of two batteries taking as single unit. So $(T \leq t) = (Y \leq t$). Thus ,

$$ P(Y \leq t) = \boxed{1 - e^{-\lambda^2 t } }$$

is this the correct distribution?

Comment: If you have two batteries in the flashlight, then typically, one would assume it stops working when one of the two battery dies, so the time until this happens is the minimum of two IID exponential RVs. You then have to take into account you’re replacing the batteries.

Comment: And when you replace the battery, can the one not used up yet continue to serve? (I know it is not quite practical) Then you got 3 batches as $\{(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)\}$ until batttery $1, 2, 3$ all run out. If not, you can just sum the life time of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most out of the batteries, we'll put two batteries in the flashlight. Once one of them expires, we'll replace it (and only it) with the third. And when another battery expires (be it the second or the third), we'll replace it with the fourth.

Let $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$ be the expiry times of the initial two batteries. Let's consider the time one of them runs out and we replace it, and and let $\Delta$ be the remaining lifetime of second. Then $\Delta = |X - Y|$.

What's the distribution of $\Delta$? To compute it, we'll need to consider the two cases, $X < Y$ and $X > Y$ in order to remove the absolute value.

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\Delta < x] &= \mathbb{P}[\Delta < x | X < Y]\mathbb{P}[X < Y] + \mathbb{P}[\Delta < x | X > Y]\mathbb{P}[X > Y] = \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}[Y - X < x | X < Y] + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}[X - Y < x | X > Y] \\
&=\mathbb{P}[Y-X < x | X < Y]
\end{align}$$

The last equality follows from symmetry: $\mathbb{P}[Y-X < x | X < Y]  = \mathbb{P}[X - Y < x | X > Y]$.

To simplify this further, we can use the [memotylessness](http://odds%20of%20a%20success%20across%20two%20levels%20of%20one%20of%20the%20explanatory%20variables) of the exponential distribution.

$$\mathbb{P}[Y - X < x | X < Y]$ = $\mathbb{P}[Y < X + x | Y > X] =
1 - \mathbb{P}[Y > X + x | Y > X] = \\=1 - \mathbb{P}[Y > x] = \mathbb{P}[Y < x]$$

This essentially shows, if $Y>X$, then $Y-X$ has the same distribution as $X$ - exponential with parameter $\lambda$. Therefore, $\Delta \sim Exp(\lambda)$.

How is this significant?

We insert two batteries with lifetimes $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim Exp(\lambda)$. One of them runs out and we replace it with the third battery. Its lifetime is $Z \sim Exp(\lambda)$. At the time of replacement, the other has lifetime $\Delta \sim Exp(\lambda)$ - the same distribution it initially had! So we're left in the same situation, just with only three batteries!

In conclusion: The time between the expiry of any two batteries is exponential with parameter $\lambda$. Once three batteries expire, the flashlight stops working, as we only have one left, and it needs two. Therefore, the working time is the sum of three $Exp(\lambda)$ random variables, which is (as seen [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27909/227435)).

$$\Gamma(3, \lambda)$$.